# List error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql

Can you help me on this error?

Mon, 15 Dec 2014 18:22:16 +0000
Error encountered during the process
The reported error was List error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS FLOAT)) AS datetime) < GETDATE()) AND company = '27074BAY') AND gages.ga' at line 6.

Here is my code,

```
    $sql_statement = "SELECT gages.*
    FROM gages
    WHERE gages.company = '$selectcomp'
    AND GAGES.isactive != '0'
    AND gages.gage_sn IN 
       (SELECT schedgi.gage_sn FROM schedgi WHERE  (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(schedgi.sched_due_date) AS FLOAT)) AS datetime) < GETDATE() AND company = '$selectcomp')
    AND gages.gage_sn NOT IN 
       ( SELECT gages.gage_sn
         FROM gages
         WHERE gages.company = '$selectcomp'  
         AND gage_sn IN 
       (SELECT  schedgi.gage_sn FROM schedgi WHERE  (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(schedgi.sched_due_date) AS FLOAT)) AS datetime) < GETDATE() AND company = '$selectcomp'))"
```

Comment: First step: Try the subquerys to see if the error is inside them

Comment: If I need to guess i would say that the error comes from the CAST statements.

Comment: can you paste your CREATE TABLE statements for both schedgi and gages please?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

Choose different names for your aliases.  FLOAT is a reserved word in MySQL:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html.

You can wrap the reserved words in backticks, but in my opinion it isn't worth the hassle.

```
SELECT something AS `FLOAT`...
```

Comment: The OP is trying casting to `FLOAT` not using it as an alias.